# Python - Wiki pages into sentences

Tags: python-3.x, wikipedia

I am trying to read a wiki page, collect and enumerate all sentences.

```
#read the wiki page

import wikipedia
eliz = wikipedia.page("Elizabeth II")
fullText2=eliz.content

m = re.split('(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)(\s|[A-Z].*)',fullText2)
docs=[]
for i in m:
  print (i)
  docs.append(i)
```

But it seems it doesn't work properly to split sentences:
for example I get this in the prints as a whole!:

> "Elizabeth received private tuition in constitutional history from
>   Henry Marten, Vice-Provost of Eton College, and learned French from a
>   succession of native-speaking governesses. A Girl Guides company, the
>   1st Buckingham Palace Company, was formed specifically so she could
>   socialise with girls her own age. Later, she was enrolled as a Sea
>   Ranger.In 1939, Elizabeth's parents toured Canada and the United
>   States. As in 1927, when her parents had toured Australia and New
>   Zealand, Elizabeth remained in Britain, since her father thought her
>   too young to undertake public tours. Elizabeth "looked tearful" as her
>   parents departed. They corresponded regularly, and she and her parents
>   made the first royal transatlantic telephone call on 18 May."

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: "Elizabeth received private tuition in constitutional history from Henry Marten..." in above is part of output.

for some sentences it works properly but for some others like above paragraph , the code doesnt work.